# Read [Outlook Options] settings with C# (Interop 15.0 or Redemption)

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, outlook-redemption

I am developing an educational application that tests users skills in Outlook and I am stuck in trying to access the settings in the [Outlook Options] dialog, more specifically the [Empty Deleted Items folders when exiting Outlook] as well as the [Check spelling as you type] option, but I will probably need others in the future as well.

I am guessing they should be somewhere in the Outlook Application model but the fact that I cannot find any option from that dialog whatsoever implies that I might be wrong.

We are also using Redemption, but as far as I could tell Redemption does not expose these properties.

So, what is the object model that exposes these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference sake. Just found the values using a registry tracking app.

The  [Empty Deleted Items folders when exiting Outlook] setting is located in

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences] 
"EmptyTrash"=dword:00000001
```

and the [Check spelling as you type] is in

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Proofing Tools\1.0\Office] 
"OutlookSpellingOptions"=dword:00000004
```

Answer (score 0):

These options are not exposed though any API. They are stored in the registry.

Comment: Lightning fast as always.You are correct of course. Just found them.